# Constant DC load stability and bandwidth slewrate

Tags: load, stability, bandwidth, rise-time, slew-rate

For this circuit, how do I know if the rise edge was limited by slew rate or bandwidth? What's the effect of R2 and C2 on bandwidth?

-3db of this circuit in simulation is 649 kHz, I know in this circuit, R1 and gate capacitance, R2//C2 , will affect bandwidth, but it doesn't add up with 2πf<sub>c</sub> formula.

NE5534 has 10 MHz bandwidth, and 13 V/µs slewrate.

I was trying to decrease C2 and R2, rising time shortened, but it comes with a stability issue, with overshoot and gain peaking. How can I break the loop in order to see its Bode plot? Also, any idea on how to increase raising time will be appreciated.

DC load Schematic:

[image: DC load Schematic]

Frequency phase analysis:

[image: Frequency phase analysis]

DC load Chart:

[image: DC load Chart]

Answer (score 1):

Without R1, R2 and C2, the circuit will be unstable because T1 has gate capacitance and the bare op-amp has a high output impedance (500-ish ohms sticks in my head as typical for most op-amps, but it's hard to get solid numbers).  That R-C circuit is inside the feedback loop, and it causes enough phase shift to make the collection oscillate.

R1 isolates the op-amp output somewhat from the gate capacitance.  C2 and R2 decrease the overall bandwidth of the op-amp to roughly 1/(R2*C2) radians/second.  This compensates the circuit for the capacitive load.

I'm not sure of the best way to break the loop, but if you just connect a resistor to the - input of the op-amp (10k or so) and drive it with a sinusoid, you should be able to monitor the output to see if it looks well behaved.  You'll basically be inferring the open-loop characteristics from the closed.

For a faster rise time, probably the best thing you can do is to find an op-amp that has a lower output impedance.  That's not a data-sheet number; I'd look for devices that are designed to drive a lot of current, or are designed to drive capacitive loads.

If you want to get a bit out on a limb, choose a nice fast, small BJT (with low base capacitance!) and connect it as an emitter follower ahead of R1.  You may have to add a resistor to ground to help turn the FET off (and to heat up your board's surroundings -- you didn't want your circuit to be TOO low power, right?).

Note that this isn't a place where I'd trust simulation much -- you'll want to prototype this with the specific op-amp you're going to use.  If you can get the attention of an applications engineer you may want to work with them -- sometimes those guys have the sort of inside information you need.

Comment: The impedance you mentioned is open loop output impedance which forms RC with C2. IRFZ44n has Ciss 1470p, if I change it to IRF530 which has Ciss 670p. I can lower C2 and R2 with same stability, and the circuit speed up a bit.

Comment: @SpringRollWang: Yup.  My emitter-follower suggestion may get you an order of magnitude of improvement, but it'd be much more work.